# The cancelation cleanup handler routine doesn't execute after thread cancelation

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, solaris-10

###### Task

I should write a program which creates a thread with printing text routine, and after two seconds of executing this thread should be canceled and the message of cancelling should be printed. The task condition is such that [phtread_cleanup_push(3C)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5168/pthread-cleanup-push-3c.html#scrolltoc) should be used for this purpose.

###### A little description of my code

I create a thread by *pthread_create()* calling with an infinity routine of text printing. The thread is created with default values of ***cancelation state*** and ***cancelation type***, so the cancelation of the created thread occurs when the thread reaches the ***cancelation point***. The main thread waits two seconds and then calls *pthread_cancel(3C)* to the child thread.

The created thread is printing the text with 0,1 second time interval using *usleep()*. Also I pasted *pthread_testcancel()* call inside infinity loop. So we have  two cancelation point inside the loop: one is the *system defined* - *usleep()* and the second is created by calling *pthread_testcancel()*.

Before the infinity loop I pasted the *pthread_cleanup_push()* with another printing text routine. And after the infinity loop I pasted *pthread_cleanup_pop()* statement, because both of this statements are implemented as the macro and according to the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5175/cancellation-5.html#REFMAN5cancellation-5) they should be in the same lexical scope.

###### Problem

Unfortunately cleanup handler routine doesn't executed. Child thread is canceling but no message about it is printing. I've been searching the answer for my problem for a long time, but nothing I've found was similar to my problem, so I'll be very thankful for any recommendation about solving my problem.

###### Code and environment

Here is my code below and it's output. I am using *Oracle VM Virtual Box* on *Windows 10 (64-bit)* on which *Oracle Solaris-10 (64-bit)* is running. I compile my program using *bash 3.2* with the command:

```bash
gcc -o lab5 -threads -lpthread -std=c99 lab5.c
```

**code:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAILED 1
#define WAIT_TIME 2
#define PRINT_DELTA_TIME 1 * 100000 // in microseconds

char* printing_text = "Child thread text\n"; // this text will be printed by child thread
char* termination_text = "Child thread is terminated\n";

void cleanup_handler(void* arg) {
  printf(termination_text);
}

// infinity routine of printing text
void *print_text() {
  pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_handler, NULL);  // push cleanup routine to the stack

  while (1) {
    pthread_testcancel();
    printf("%s\n", printing_text);
    usleep(PRINT_DELTA_TIME);
  }
  pthread_cleanup_pop(1);

  return NULL;
}

// cancel a thread with exception handling
int try_cancel_thread(pthread_t *thread) {
  int code = pthread_cancel(*thread);

  if (code != SUCCESS) {
        char* error_message = strerror(code);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s%s\n", "can't cancel a child thread:", error_message);

        return FAILED;
  }
  return SUCCESS;
}

// creating a thread with exception handling
int try_create_thread(pthread_t *thread) {
  int code = pthread_create(thread, NULL, print_text, NULL);

  if (code != SUCCESS) {
        char* error_message = strerror(code);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s%s\n", "can't create a child thread:", error_message);

        return FAILED;
  }
  return SUCCESS;
}

int main() {
  pthread_t child_thread;

  if (try_create_thread(&child_thread) == FAILED) {return FAILED;}

  sleep(WAIT_TIME);

  if (try_cancel_thread(&child_thread) == FAILED) {return FAILED;}

  printf("the execution is succefully completed\n");
  
  return SUCCESS;
}

#undef SUCCESS
#undef FAILED
#undef WAIT_TIME
#undef PRINT_DELTA_TIME
```

**output:**

```
Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

Child thread text

the execution is succefully completed
```

Comment: Your thread is killed as soon as `main` returns and might not have enough time to execute its handler. Try to add some delay after cancelling the thread.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, you are right,  I didn't take that into account. After adding the _pthread_join()_ statement before returning from _main()_  cancelation cleanup routine successfully executed. Thank you!